# One error in running time in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, exception

When I run my website,sometimes run without error and some times this exception accord. what's problem?

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback
>   or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes,
>   this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events
>   originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If
>   the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1503660/290343

Comment: I can't understand exactly how handle this exception. I need some explain more

Comment: There can be various reasons, please read the answers thoroughly, including Microsoft's documentation about [EnableEventValdidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enableeventvalidation.aspx). Depending on your security needs, as a last resort (but only a last resort), set it to 'false' in web.config or on a per-page basis.

Comment: this document hasn't a sample , and I can't understand

Comment: should I add <pages enableEventValidation="true"> in web.config? where of web.config should I put this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1503660/290343.

Also read Microsoft's documentation about [EnableEventValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enableeventvalidation.aspx). Depending on your security needs, as a last resort (but only a last resort), set it to 'false' in web.config or on a per-page basis.