# ASP.NET Gridview Selected Index Changed not firing

Tags: asp.net, events, gridview

This has been asked quite a few times, but still.

In GridView is defined event OnSelectedIndexChanged. My expectation is, that if I click on a row in gridview, the event will be fired. I managed to do the same with image buttons, but I want the entire row to be clickable.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gameGrid" PageSize="20" PagerSettings-Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast"
    OnRowDataBound="GameGrid_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GameGrid_PageIndexChanging"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" AllowPaging="True"
    AllowSorting="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gameGrid_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Game Id" DataField="ID_Game" SortExpression="ID_Game" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Player" DataField="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Finshed" SortExpression="Finished" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Started At" SortExpression="CreateDate" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Updated At" SortExpression="LastUpdate" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I was assuming that if I define an EventHandler in CodeBehind, it will be fired.

```
protected void gameGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
}
```

Why is this event not firing?

I would like to redirect the user on a different page with an ID parameter in URL. Should I do something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the `AutoGenerateSelectButton` property to true in the GridView. This will generate a LinkButton. Now in the `RowDataBound` event do the following.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //find the select button in the row (in this case the first control in the first cell)
        LinkButton lb = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as LinkButton;

        //hide the button, but it still needs to be on the page
        lb.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");

        //add the click event to the gridview row
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink((GridView)sender, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex));
    }
}
```

You could add the OnClick event to the row without showing the `SelectButton`, but then you would to turn off `EnableEventValidation` as seen here [How to create a gridview row clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720534/how-to-create-a-gridview-row-clickable)

Comment: I found a little bit more elegant solution, in my opinion (RowDataBound Event). 
  `e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", String.Format("window.location='Play.aspx?GID={0}&UID={1}'", v_GameOverview.ID_Game, v_GameOverview.Email));`