# GridView PageIndexChanging not firing, I don't know why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, webforms

The paging not working on my gridView, I don't know why ?:

load methode :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  {if (!(Session["id"] is null))
 {
           if(!IsPostBack)
           GridBind();
 }
```

databind methode :

```
private void GridBind()
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("ASP_importerConduire", cn);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "conduire");
            gv_conduire.DataSource = ds.Tables["conduire"];
            gv_conduire.DataBind();
        }
```

PageIndexChanging event :

```
protected void gv_conduire_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gv_conduire.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridBind();
}
```

the code aspx :

```
<asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" ID="gv_conduire" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_conduire_PageIndexChanging">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="NC" HeaderText="Nom complet" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="matricule" HeaderText="Matricule du véhicule" />
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Is the control's (gv_conduire) PostBack property set to True?

Comment: the gridview don't have any property calls 'PostBack'

Comment: that's right... the Microsoft DataGridView doesn't have a AutoPostBack property.  Sorry about that.  This is what we did for a workaround: (AutoGenerateSelectButton): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781635/asp-net-gridview-selected-index-changed-not-firing

Comment: It's okay Pete, but my problem is when I click to go to the page number 2 or 3 or ....., nothing happen, always I get the first page of the the gridview  ,that's mean that the PageIndexChanging event not firing

Comment: I should read and comprehend your question better... the problem isn't selecting the row, but paging.  My apologies AGAIN!

Comment: it's okay Pete, thank you

Comment: Maybe it's because you're rebinding the data OnPageIndexChanging with the GridBind() function? That might be resetting the paging somehow.

Comment: I must rebind to get always the newest data