# Drop ASP.Net Drop Down SelectedIndex_Changed Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have the following code for the DropDown Selected Index Changed. But It's not firing the event as expected

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropCourseLevel" runat="server" CssClass="form-control m-input" 
AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropCourseLevel_SelectedIndexChanged" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I'm getting the following error in the Console

> Uncaught Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

Any Help is much appreciated

Comment: Look at your `Page_Load`. I guess there is code which databinds the page and this dropdown. Do that only `if(!IsPostBack)`.

Comment: Please check the additional error information added

Comment: Have you serached this error on stackoverflow? You will find the answer. Do you change the content of the dropdown via javascript?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was Able to resolve the Issue by adding EnableEventValidation="false" on my page's code. Thanks For the Response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Setting this property on your aspx page as:

```
EnableEventValidation="false"
```

Comment: Thanks. That Solved My Issue

Comment: Related answer (with more background info): https://stackoverflow.com/q/1503630/1220550

Comment: Thanks for the Info @PeterB. i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I was Able to resolve the Issue by adding `EnableEventValidation="false"` on my 
page's code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="false" 
CodeBehind="Application.aspx.cs" Inherits="USI.User.Application" 
Title="Course Application" MasterPageFile="~/User/MyPage.Master" %>
```